# How do I make sure the first option of a radio group element is selected by default in this Angular Material app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am working on a form in Angular.

In `form.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormService } from '../services/form.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css'],
})
export class FormComponent {
  public accountTypes!: any;
  public selectedAccountType: any;

  public form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    first_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    last_name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    accountInfo: new FormGroup({
      account_type: new FormControl(''),
    }),
  });

  constructor(private formService: FormService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccountTypes();
  }

  public getAccountTypes() {
    this.formService.getAccountTypes().subscribe((response) => {
      this.accountTypes = response;
    });
  }

  public sendFormData() {
    console.log(this.form);
  }
}
```

The form's template:

```
<h1>Get in touch</h1>

<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Fast name:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="first_name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Last name:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="last_name" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="never">
      <mat-label class="mat-label">Email:</mat-label>
      <input class="mat-input" matInput formControlName="email" />
    </mat-form-field>

    <div formGroupName="accountInfo">
      <mat-radio-group
        formControlName="account_type"
        [(ngModel)]="this.selectedAccountType"
      >
        <mat-radio-button
          *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes"
          [value]="accountType.value"
        >
          <span class="top-label">{{ accountType.label }}</span>
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <button
      (click)="sendFormData()"
      mat-raised-button
      color="primary"
      [disabled]="!form.valid"
    >
      Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

See **[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-fcndvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.css)** Stackblitz.

#### The problem

If the user forgets to select a radio button, there is no viable way, from a visual standpoint, to signal  the `<mat-radio-group>` as invalid. I want *the first option to be selected by default*, instead.

I have not been able to achieve this goal.

###### What is the easiest and most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: **never** [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way you can use is `patchValue()` for the formControl.

**form.component.html**

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="account_type">
  <mat-radio-button
    *ngFor="let accountType of accountTypes"
    [value]="accountType.value"
  >
    <span class="top-label">{{ accountType.label }}</span>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

> ***If you use Reactive Form then there is no need to have `ngModel` for that, so I have removed it.***

**form.component.ts**

```
public getAccountTypes() {
    this.formService.getAccountTypes().subscribe((response) => {
      this.accountTypes = response;
      this.form.controls['accountInfo'].patchValue({
          account_type: response[0].value, // use index as per your choice.
      });
    });
  }
```

To know more about Reactive forms and it's method please refer this link: [Reactive Forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms.)

Please refer this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-qf4e1o?file=src/app/form/form.component.html) Repo for more clarification.

Comment: I get a `Property 'response' does not exist on type 'FormComponent'` error.

Comment: Please update your code on stackblitz. Mean time refer this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-modal-demo-v6tvhx?file=src/app/form/form.component.ts

Comment: The `account_type` form field is nested, I apologies for not mentioning this from the beginning, as I did not think it was relevant. It obviously is relevant. I have updated the question and Stackblitz.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, I have updated the code and added the Stackblitz link as well.

Comment: BTW, what is the syntax for going into form groups to patch value? Is it this?
`this.form.controls['formGroupLevelOne.formGroupLevelTwo'].patchValue({
  account_type: response[0].value,
});`

Comment: There are many ways..You will get know by practice..Just refer official documentation of Angular which I have provided in the answer...Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[checked]** attribute on the radio button element to set the first option as selected by default.

For example,

```
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value="option1" checked>Option 1</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="option2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="option3">Option 3</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: I don't hardcode every `<mat-radio-button>`, I use an `*ngFor`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngModel

For example:
*Html file:

```
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<mat-radio-group
  aria-labelledby="example-radio-group-label"
  class="example-radio-group"
  [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season">
    {{season}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div>Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
```

Ts file:

```
favoriteSeason: string;
  seasons: any[]=[];
```

After call api sessions:

```
favoriteSeason = sessions[0]
```

Ref link: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/examples

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this in your ngOnInIt:

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAccountTypes();
    this.selectedAccountType = 'value 1';
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.